# Bash Script: No such file or directory when defining variable via source vars.txt

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, scripting

I have a script that creates a hash of a file, writes it to vars.txt and then checks that variable next time the script is run to determine if the file has changed.

[Here is the script](http://pastebin.com/QQGHGBKR) and  [vars.txt](http://pastebin.com/WJgwVdkt) (pastebin)

When I run the script I call the variable with `source /path/to/file`

This now gives me the following error when the file is parsed:

```
/opt/scripts/AutoCommit/vars.txt: line 2: etchttpdconf_dvhost.conf=925ec4d7bd0dc94c3710bcf5fb2c80f422806bb5  /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf: No such file or directory
```

On top of that, when the file changes `sed` is now not replacing the line but adding an additional line underneath. It had not done this in the past.

You get a file that ends up [like this.](http://pastebin.com/1Nv9hdss) Until recently this did not happen so I suspect they are both caused by the same issue.

[Here is a stripped down version of the script, where I believe the problem may be.](http://pastebin.com/R7ZECL2K)

Comment: your `.` isnt getting handled, i think? does the bash `${///}` var stuff treat dots like `sed` does? because a `.` dot to `sed` has to be escaped `\.` to literally mean *dot*, else it means *any single character*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your

```
fileVarName="${fileVarName/./_}"
```

to do all dots

```
fileVarName="${fileVarName//./_}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.` (dot) is not a valid character in a variable name, as defined in your `vars.txt`:

> ```
> gitinstalled="1"
> etchttpdconf_dvhost.conf="925ec4d7bd0dc94c3710bcf5fb2c80f422806bb5  /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf"
> etchttpdconf_dvhost.conf="925ec4d7bd0dc94c3710bcf5fb2c80f422806bb5  /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf"
> ```

Comment: i didnt look very hard at it, but it appeared that the main script is supposed to be replacing `.` dots with `_` underscores or something.

Comment: @mikeserv I too stopped looking after I realised that the script was the full thing rather than a cut-down version that illustrated the problem.

Comment: well, i dunno, i think the problem might be in the 40 `echo` lines somewhere, maybe, too